# Switch to mobile site dynamically for iOS 13+

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile, user-agent

In iPad iOS 13+, Safari browser loads website in desktop mode by default. There is a way to switch to mobile site by clicking "AA" button on URL bar.

Is there any way to switch to mobile site using JavaScript/jQuery?

I'm able to get userAgent string and differentiate between desktop and mobile mode but could not find any source to do the switch?

> **iPad Desktop site**
>
> userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (JHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15
>
> **iPad Mobile site**
>
> userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 14_0_1 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like GEcko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148
> Safari/604.1

Can anyone point to right direction?